# Installation of tensor flow on windows

Tags: tensorflow, pip

When I installed tensor flow, after type following command
`pip3 install --upgrade tensor flow`
following issue rose up

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensor flow
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensor flow

any solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow is very easy to install, just follow the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/), you will finish it easily. In you install command you should use `tensorflow` not `tensor flow`.

Answer (score 1):

"tensorflow" is one word, the correct installation command is:

`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

Also, it should be noted TensorFlow for Windows only supports 64bit architecture, if you have a 32bit installation of python, it will give you this error.

You can check your architecture by running:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

Answer (score 0):

"tensorflow" is very easy to install. there are two ways to install.

1st way:

you need to download the tensorflow whl file from link [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Once you are done with downloading.
open a cmd.exe and type

```
    pip install <file_location>\<filename.whl>
```

and hit enter.
It will install the library in your system.

2nd option:
you can go to the link [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/install/install_windows). and follow the instruction for windows.

**make sure you install python 3.5**

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. He has a very specific question - and your answer is on a super generic level - not at all taking into account what the question is specifically asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Verify the installation

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

your mistake is that you're writing it separately.  `pip3 install --upgrade tensor flow`